# Logstash not reading spring properties correctly

Tags: java, spring, logging, logstash, properties-file

So I have a quite simple logstash configuration that should read the host URL from spring. Although for some reason it is not working.

My `logback-spring.xml` looks sort of like this:

```
  <springProperty name="logstashDestination" scope="context" source="service.logstash.host"/>
  <appender class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender" name="LOGSTASH">
    <destination>${logstashDestination}</destination>

    <!-- encoder is required -->
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
      <customFields>{"service":"provisioning-engine-jane"}</customFields>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```

In my `application.properties` I have these lines:

```
spring.profiles.active:sit
service.logstash.host:NaN
```

And in `application-sit.properties` I have this line:

```
service.logstash.host:api-test.local:9013
```

This makes the whole application crash with the error

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@44cb3536 - Could not invoke method addDestination in class net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender with parameter of type java.lang.String java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
ERROR in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[LOGSTASH] - No destination was configured. Use <destination> to add one or more destinations to the appender
```

The odd thing here is that if I add a `bootstrap.properties` file with some dummy data it starts. Issue with this is that the dummy data is overriding my environment specific logstash URL.

Anyone have any idea of why this might be happening?

Comment: Where is your logback-spring.xml file located?

Comment: Same error as soon as I updated from 5.x to 6.x